# Xcode 7: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) again

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

Im testing my app on iOS simulator of Xcode 7 and its all right o, but when i try test in my iOSDevice (a iPhone 5S with iOS 9).
I updated the xcode 7 and iOS9 today (09/16/2015) and before that with iOS 8.4 was working fine.

OBS: The iOS Deployment target on Xcode project is iOS 9.

I already try this:
http://twobitlabs.com/2011/06/adding-ocunit-to-an-existing-ios-project-with-xcode-4/ like suggested in this post:
[clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) when doing unit test on xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079764/clang-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation) but doesn't work.

The guy of this post, just created a new project:
[xCode 7: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173075/xcode-7-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-use-v-to-see-invocation) But is not a solution to me, because my project is huge.

Comment: Show the actual linker errors, verbatim.

Comment: ld: file not found: /Users/thiagoarreguy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GameExchange-faojxjqwsvtwcscomllihciaafny/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GameExchange.app/GameExchange
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: See my build settings LINKING Bundle Loader: http://imgur.com/qFMEENf

See the path in finder: http://imgur.com/Od4mFu4

Comment: I resolve my problem: i created a new project, so put the window with the build settings side by side with my project and change in my project the different values... One of this changes was "Enable Bitcode: NO"

Answer (score 22):

To solve this problem:

1. Go to your project setting page
2. Select your project (left side)
3. Click the "Build Settings" tab
4. Search "Bitcode"
5. Set "Enable Bitcode" to "No"

Comment: iOS Deployment target on Xcode project is iOS 9, XCode 7, iOS9

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by select device instead of simulator to install the app. as libs i was using not support the linker for simulator.